# Terminate Gradient Descent Algorithm when two iterations are “very similar”

Tags: r, terminate, gradient-descent

I implemented the Gradient Descent Algorithm in R to find the minimum of the function f(x)=1−xe−x which works wonderfully and gives me [1] 1 as output, but keeps iterating until all 30.000 iterations are over, even if there are only slight changes (many digits behind the decimal point) between the iterations.

How can I add some function to the code, that terminates it as soon as the last two iterations are very similar?

this is my code:

```
# learning rate
epsilon = 0.02

# set up a number of iteration
iter = 30000

# define the gradient of f(x) with given f'(x)
gradient = function(x) return(-exp(-x) + x * exp(-x))

# randomly initialize the x
x = 8

# create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
x.All = vector("numeric",iter)

# gradient descent method to find the minimum
for(i in 1:iter){
  x = x - epsilon*gradient(x)
  x.All[i] = x
  print(x)
}
```

I tried things like adding the following without effect.

```
round (x, digits = 3)
if (x == x - epsilon*gradient) {
break}
```

I suppose as floating point number x never equals x - epsilon*gradient exactly?

Comment: I'd never say never. But, for this case, best to use a condition like like `abs(old_x - new_x) <= small_value` to terminate for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a problem with the stopping rule you consider:

```
if (x == x - epsilon*gradient) break
```

The condition will be met only if `epsilon * gradient` is exactly zero, but the loop should stop when that quantity is sufficiently close to zero. So for instance, if `espilon=1` and defining `eps2` to be a small number (0.0001), this

```
if (abs(gradient(x)) < eps2) break
```

would work.

Comment: Works perfectly. New Syntax  stops iterating before the number of "iter" is reached when it comes close enough. I just integrated your if statement into my for statement.